# How to click on item list in other activity using robotium?

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I have button in my application that opens android contact application for choose contact from list in other words I need to click on list item in other activity. How I can do it using robotium ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robotium can only test one application at a time.

Here is a link that will answer questions like that: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers